# Add external javascript file to React.js app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router

I'm having a little problem adding external javaScript file to my React App. I tried so many things but none of them worked. The last thing I did is:

step#1 : creating JS file and create functions.

step#2 : import the functions form my js file.

step#3 : call the functions.

The issue is when I run: npm start, everything work fine. But when I  run: nom build, the script won't work!

This is my js file that I created with exporting functions

```
            export function BackgroundMove() {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                let movementStrength = 25;
                let height = movementStrength / $(window).height();
                let width = movementStrength / $(window).width();
                $("body").mousemove(function(e){
                        let pageX = e.pageX - ($(window).width() / 2);
                        let pageY = e.pageY - ($(window).height() / 2);
                        let newvalueX = width * pageX * -1 - 25;
                        let newvalueY = height * pageY * -1 - 50;
                        $('body').css("background-position", newvalueX+"px     "+newvalueY+"px");
                });
                });
            }


            export function HeaderMove() {
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('#nav-icon0,#nav-icon1,#nav-icon2,#nav-icon3,#nav-icon4').click(function(){
                        $(this).toggleClass('open');
                    });
                });
            }
```

Here I'm importing my functions

```
    import {HeaderMove, BackgroundMove} from '../../style';
```

Calling the functions:

```
   componentDidMount() {
      HeaderMove();
      BackgroundMove();
    }
```

As I mentioned, this will work fine when I run

```
 npm start
```

But, when I run

```
npm build
```

my script won't work

Comment: Why you don't add this script to index.html?

Comment: I tried, it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the following code to import external javascript file inside component:

```
componentDidMount() {
   var script = document.createElement('script')
   script.src = // path of external javascript file.
   script.class = "external-script"
   document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

and inside componentWillUnmount you can remove that file using the class name.

Comment: Thanks Piyush, I'm having a little problem understanding your code.       script.class = "external-script".      Is the "external-script"  the name of the js file or the function?