# Is there any way to import JavaScript function to React component outside from src folder

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs

I have a two function at my javascript utils.js at my django static files. I want to use this file common with react. So i want to import to react this file with functions and i want to use it at react component. Function example

```
function convertMsToDatetime(s) {
    let ms = s % 1000;
    s = (s - ms) / 1000;
    let secs = s % 60;
    s = (s - secs) / 60;
    let mins = s % 60;
    s = (s - mins) / 60;
    let hours = s % 24
    let day = (s - hours) / 24

    var ret = [];
    if (day !== 0) {
        ret.push(day + "d")
    }

    if (hours !== 0) {
        ret.push(hours + "h")
    }
    if (mins !== 0) {
        ret.push(mins + "m")
    }
    if (secs !== 0) {
        ret.push(secs + "s")
    }
    return ret.join(" ")
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53974071/add-external-javascript-file-to-react-js-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add `export` in the function that you want it.

```
export function convertMsToDatetime() {
   // do something
}
```

Then, in the file you want to use it add these:

```
import myFunc from './file_name';
myFunc.convertMsToDatetime()
```

Maybe, if you don't know it. When you use the `./` to some route, you are just refering to the folder that contains your actual file.

Comment: But with this way this js file must be in react src folder right ? But i want to put some other forlder

Comment: Not necessarily. You can use it wherever you want. Src folder is just a folder like other. The diference is that understands in there is going to be all the code. For example the js file could be at the root './js/my-file.js' and your component at './src/components/my-component.js/ you can call it using './../../js/my-file.js'